# Download files from href and looping all files to save in separate tabs in a workbook in C drive

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to download files from href and saving the data through loop in separate tabs in worksheet on C drive.

Thanks to Tim Williams for helping me putting the code till i get downloading the href files. But code putting to copy the downloaded data to excel. this is not working for me.

```
Sub download()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim el As Object, els As Object

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.nafed-india.com/Home/ProcDispoDetails"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With

    'Note: querySelectorAll unless you only want one element
    Set els = ie.document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='/Documents/ProcurementDisposal']")
    For Each el In els
        Debug.Print el.href 

    Dim i As Long

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\Sample.xlsx"

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
    Workbooks.Worksheets(i).Range("a1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = el.herf(i)
    Next i

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWindow.Close
        Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.
Adjust to suit your exact situation.

```
Sub download()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer, i As Long
    Dim el As Object, els As Object, wb As Workbook, smpl as workbook

    Set smpl = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\Desktop\Sample.xlsx")

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "http://www.nafed-india.com/Home/ProcDispoDetails"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With

    'Note: querySelectorAll unless you only want one element
    Set els = ie.document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='/Documents/ProcurementDisposal']")
    i = 1
    For Each el In els
        Debug.Print el.href 
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(el.href)
        wb.sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy smpl.Sheets(i).Range("A1")
        wb.close false
        i = i +1
   Next el

   smpl.Save

End Sub
```

Note: it's polite to accept any answers which helped you - this helps people who come along later and look at your question to know what responses worked.  Take a few minutes to do that for your previous posts - if you neglect that you may find help dries up...

Comment: Thanks again for the solution Tim Williams! I accepted the answer. Great help!

Comment: I am getting the runtime error at here wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy smpl.Sheets(i).Range("A1")

Comment: Now i am getting the Compile error user defined type not defined for "Dim ie As InternetExplorer".                                                                          Earlier I got Run Time Error for " wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy smpl.Sheets(i).Range("A1")"

Comment: User-defined type not defined typically indicates you've not added a required reference to your VBA project.

Comment: Yes Williams, it is working with Tools>reference> Microsoft internet Controls is on. However, it is partially copying some data into excel and rest not getting copied. please need help to understand on that.

Comment: What is missing?  I have no idea what your workbooks look like, so you will need to be a bit more specific (eg provide a concrete example)

Comment: You could try instead:  `wb.sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy smpl.Sheets(i).Range("A1")`